# Normalize Text - writing methods of encrypting and decrypting text

Tags: java

Im working on the following task:

Write a method called normalizeText() which does the following:

> -Removes all the spaces from your text
>
> -Remove any punctuation (. , : ; ’ ” ! ? ( ) )
>
> -Turn all lower-case letters into upper-case letters
>
> -Return the result.

The call `normalizeText("This is some \"really\" great. (Text)!?"`

should return `"THISISSOMEREALLYGREATTEXT"`.

Here is what i came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Crypto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        normalizeText();
    }

    public static String normalizeText() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert your Text : ");
        String crypto = input.next();

        crypto.replace("\\s", "");
        crypto.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
        crypto.toUpperCase();

        System.out.println(crypto);

        return crypto;
    }
}
```

For every sentence I input, I get just the first word of the sentence printed, without further String changes (Insert your Text : `"asdfg asdf asd"`, returns `"asdfg"`). As you can see, I'm a beginner and asking for help in the form of hints.

Comment: That is what `input.next` does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` method, because `next` method only reads the first word of you sentence, that's why you see the first word in the output. you can read [this link](https://www.includehelp.com/java/difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods.aspx) for more information.

```
String crypto = input.nextLine();
```

and about the wanted task for removing spaces and punctuations, i strongly recommend you to take advantage of [Regex](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expressions-in-java/) instead.